# How to remove the contacts

Tags: contacts

My daughter (7 years old) has a tablet. However, Google won't allow her to create an account due to her age. As such, she is using mine.

The issue is, she has access to all my contacts. I would like to only allow her access to the contacts she adds and not the ones I have associated with the account she is using (seems counter intuitive when I write this).

Whilst the obvious answer is create a new account and lie about her age, my question is if I can remove access to the shared contacts and only provide her local contacts. EG, she can't access any contacts under Google Contacts but can from her local device (such as her parents and friends email address).

Comment: This is likely impossible. Google keeps all contacts in one account. I recommend just making her fake age to be 14 or something.

Comment: I'll agree with @MarkYisri here. Some devices can filter between SIM, local, Google, Skype, Facebook and other types of contacts I think. My old Samsung used to at least. But why take the chance? Create a new account and have no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Probably creating your second email ID or creating her fake email ID will be the easiest solution. But try this -

With each Google account you have privilege to Sync only thing you want. I better recommend you to go to Settings on Android, then tap on Account > select Google and tap on your email ID and turn off **Sync Contacts**. I read it on [Selective Sync Google Account Settings](http://technosamigos.com/selective-sync-google-account-settings/) and I believe that should work.